# SQL Server logic for where dataset in dataset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dataset, where-clause

First we have the code and after that we have the actual question.

A function for splitting strings. I found this somewhere online and I haven't yet bothered to check the quality of it. I only add the function here for making the question more complete.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (
      @InputString                  NVARCHAR(4000),
      @Delimiter                    NVARCHAR(50)
)

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
      Item                          NVARCHAR(4000)
)

AS
BEGIN
      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END

      IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
            SET @Delimiter = ','

--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Delimiter) -- Diagnostic
--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString) -- Diagnostic

      DECLARE @Item                 NVARCHAR(4000)
      DECLARE @ItemList       NVARCHAR(4000)
      DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

      SET @ItemList = @InputString
      SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

            -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      END -- End WHILE

      IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
      END

      -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
      ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

      RETURN

END -- End Function
GO
```

And then we have my code. The code has been altered for simplicity.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Rule] (
    RuleID INT,
    RuleCode NVARCHAR(255),
    RuleFormula NVARCHAR(MAX),
    TableKey INT,
    RelatedTables NVARCHAR(1000)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.[rule] (RuleID, RuleCode, RuleFormula, TableKey, RelatedTables)
SELECT 1, 'Code1', 'Someformula', 1, 'TableA|TableB|TableC|TableD'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Code2', 'Someformula', 1, 'TableA|TableB|TableC'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Code3', 'Someformula', 1, 'TableA|TableB';
GO
```

And then we have the procedure that I need help with. I know full well that the last line of the where clause is incorrect but I have included it to show what kind of solution that I am trying to achieve.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RuleGet]
@TableKey INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @RelatedTables TABLE (
    RelatedTableCode NVARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO @RelatedTables (RelatedTableCode)
SELECT 'TableA'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'TableB'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TableC';

SELECT
    RuleId,
    RuleCode,
    RuleFormula
FROM [dbo].[Rule] 
WHERE @TableKey = TableKey
AND (SELECT item FROM [dbo].[Split](RelatedTables, '|')) IN (SELECT RelatedTableCode FROM @RelatedTables);

END
GO
```

What I want to achieve is that the rules returned by the stored procedure should filter off on TableKey (as it does) but also on the condition that a Rule should only be retrieved if all of the RelatedTable codes, for that rule, exist in the @RelatedTables list.

In this example I only want rules 2 and 3 to be returned by the stored procedure.

This could easily be solved using a loop of some sort but I want this solved in a set based way as my semi-mock code has outlined.

We are using SQL Server 2014 standard edition.

Many thanks!

Comment: Search for "relational division in SQL".

Answer (score 1):

If you can ensure that the values in `Rule.RelatedTables` contain the table names in alphabetical order, you could do this:

```
    SELECT
        RuleId,
        RuleCode,
        RuleFormula
    FROM [dbo].[Rule] 
    WHERE @TableKey = TableKey
    AND CHARINDEX(RelatedTables, (SELECT STUFF((SELECT '|' + RelatedTableCode 
                                                FROM @RelatedTables
                                                GROUP BY RelatedTableCode
                                                ORDER BY RelatedTableCode
                                                FOR XML PATH('')
                                                ), 1, 1, ''))) <> 0
```

This effectively condenses the contents of the `@RelatedTables` variable into the same format as the values in `Rule.RelatedTables`, then checks whether the latter is a substring of the former, which I believe should give you the behaviour you want.

For what it's worth, I definitely wouldn't do it this way (even if I think I can guarantee the order of the values encoded into `Rule.RelatedTables`), I'd probably create a function which takes two parameters (the `@RelatedTables` table variable and a varchar containing a `Rule.RelatedTables` value) and evaluates them against each other procedurally (as you allude to in your question), returning a Boolean to indicate whether they match sufficiently or not.